# Uncaught ReferenceError: vira1 is not defined

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, ionic2, typescript

Estou criando uma função mas quando é chamada diz que não foi definido ainda, qual seria o motivo ?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-jogomemoria',
  templateUrl: 'jogomemoria.html',
})
export class JogomemoriaPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

 
}
function vira1(){
 document.getElementById("vira0").style.zIndex = "999";
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding class="bgcMemoria">
  <div class="fase1">
    <div class="viradasBaixo">
      <img src="assets/img/carta.jpg" id="viradaBaixo1" onclick="vira1()">
    </div>
    <div class="viradasCima" id="viradasCima">
      <img src="assets/img/virada.jpg" id="vira0"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Em vez de `onclick=` utilize `(click)=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do *Angular 2* para fazer *binding* de eventos usa-se parênteses, toda vez que quiser chamar um evento faça `(evento)="exeFuncao()"`

Alguns eventos:

```
(focus)="exeFuncao()"
(blur)="exeFuncao()"

(submit)="exeFuncao()"

(scroll)="exeFuncao()"

(cut)="exeFuncao()"
(copy)="exeFuncao()"
(paste)="exeFuncao()"

(keydown)="exeFuncao()"
(keypress)="exeFuncao()"
(keyup)="exeFuncao()"

(mouseenter)="exeFuncao()"
(mousedown)="exeFuncao()"
(mouseup)="exeFuncao()"

(click)="exeFuncao()"
(dblclick)="exeFuncao()"

(drag)="exeFuncao()"
(dragover)="exeFuncao()"
(drop)="exeFuncao()"
```

Você pode ver a lista completa nesse [artigo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events) no sitio da *Mozilla*.

Outro erro, é que seu método `vira1` está fora da classe `JogomemoriaPage` então não ira funcionar.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-jogomemoria',
    templateUrl: 'jogomemoria.html',
})
export class JogomemoriaPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    }
    vira1(){
        document.getElementById("vira0").style.zIndex = "999";
    }
}
```

Comment: E para declarar uma variável ai dentro ? Estou tentando mas fica dando erro não seria assim ? "let variavel: any = 0;" fica mostrando erro no let

Comment: Que variável? Porque na pergunta não tem, ai já é outro problema, que recomendo abrir outra pergunta, pois vou ter que sinalizar como ampla. Quando criar uma pergunta certifique de ter colocado todos os detalhes.

Comment: Abri outra pergunta com mais detalhes

Comment: Mas tenta colocar a variável no método `constructor` sem o `let`.

Comment: Certo, agora se a resposta solucionou esse problema considere marcar como aceita.